# Spring Data JPA/Hibernate OneToMany remove ManyToOne Child

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am experiencing the following problem:

I have 3 Pojo's

- Artist
- Album
- Track

With the Artist having a OneToMany relationship with Album, and Album having a OneToMany relationship with Track.

Artist.class

```
@Entity
public class Artist {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "artist_id")
    private long artist_id;

    @Column(name = "artist_name", nullable = false, length = 32)
    private String artist_name;

    @Column(name = "artist_bio", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String artist_bio;

    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(name = "artist_avatar")
    private byte[] artist_avatar;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "artist", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Album> albumList;
```

Album.class

```
@Entity
public class Album {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "album_id")
    private long album_id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "artist_id", nullable = false)
    private Artist artist;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "album", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Track> trackList;

    @Column(name = "album_name", nullable = false, length = 32)
    private String album_name;

    @Column(name = "album_description", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String album_description;

    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(name = "album_avatar")
    private byte[] album_avatar;
```

Track.class

```
@Entity
public class Track {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "track_id")
    private long track_id;

    @Column(name = "track_no", nullable = false, length = 2)
    private String track_no;

    @Column(name = "track_name", nullable = false, length = 32)
    private String track_name;

    @Column(name = "track_length", nullable = false, length = 32)
    private String track_length;

    @Column(name = "track_file", nullable = false, length = 128)
    private String track_file;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "album_id", nullable = false)
    private Album album;
```

Track Controller.class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/track", params = "delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Transactional
public String postDeleteTrack(@RequestParam Long album_id, Long track_id) {
    trackService.deleteTrack(track_id);
    return "redirect:album/" + album_id;
}
```

Track Service.class

```
public void deleteTrack(Long track_id) {
    trackRepository.delete(track_id);
}
```

TrackRepository.class

```
@Repository
public interface TrackRepository extends CrudRepository<Track, Long>{
}
```

When I call the trackService.deleteTrack(track_id); the track in my MySQL database isn't deleted.
Hibernate just gives me a lot of select statements as output.

Any help is appreciated and if you need more information from me feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you post your delete method?

Comment: And did you remove the track from Album trackList collection?

Comment: My delete method is just a repository i use from the spring-data.

@Repository
public interface TrackRepository extends CrudRepository<Track, Long>{
}

Can you explain to me a litter better what you mean with removing the album trackList collection? I don't have a lot experience with orm frameworks like hibernate.

Comment: I Have the same problem. Do you have found a way to get it work?

Comment: Its ben a while but the way I think I got this working is by:
<pre> <code>
@OneTomany(mappedBy = album)
List<Track> tracks;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "album_id")
private Album album;
</pre> </code>

Comment: Yeah, see my previous comment. Does it solve your problem as well?

Answer (score 0):

In your repository method, add  this

```
@Query("delete  from Track t where t.id=:id") 
void  delete(@Param("id")String id);
```

Since you didnt override the cascade policy,default cascade policy is none, i believe this will work.
reference- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html_single/